# HTML & CSS Text Wrap with some items styled differently from others

Tags: html, css

I want to have a container of fixed width, the tags need to be differently styled, but wrap within the container. Any ideas?

```css
div {
  width: 200px;
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.6);
  margin: 10px;
  padding: 10px;
}
p {
  margin: 0px;
  color: white;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-weight: 100;
}
p:nth-child(1) {
  font-weight: 600;  
}
```

```html
<div>
  <p>This Text in BOLD.</p>
  <p>And we want this in normal weight but we want it to wrap as it is doing in the second example.</p>
</div>
<div>
  <p>This Text in BOLD. And we want this in normal weight but we want it to wrap as it is doing in the second example.</p>
</div>
```

Comment: depends on the font.... `sans-serif` depends on OS/browser.

Comment: what you want exactly?

Comment: Looks like you need to use `<span>` and `classes` to get the results that you are looking for. not everything can be done with just a `<p>`

Comment: If **you know** the actual change in the character sizes you **might** be able to play with `letter-spacing` but frankly, this is a losing battle and **entirely** typeface/font dependant. Text will wrap where it wants to in the main.

Comment: @Paulie_D does the `ch` unit change with font-weight ?

Comment: @AnkithAmtange Yes, I would expect so and typeface too.

Comment: I want the fist p to be in BOLD and for the text in the second p to immediately follow it, ie. the second p should NOT start on the following line.

Comment: I figured it out, let's see if I can answer my own question....

Answer (score 2):

```css
div {
  width: 200px;
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.6);
  margin: 10px;
  padding: 10px;
}
p{
  margin: 0px;
  color: white;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-weight: 100;      
}
span {
  font-weight: 600;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <p><span>This Text in BOLD.</span> And we want this in normal weight but we want it to wrap as it is doing in the second example.</p>
</div>
```

Comment: That is the sensible way to do it.  Thanks.

Comment: This guy has your answer.

Answer (score 0):

Use ID's? See below.

```css
div {
  width: 200px;
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.6);
  margin: 10px;
  padding: 10px;
}
p{
  margin: 0px;
  color: white;
  font-family: sans-serif;
}
p#one {
  font-weight: 100;
}
p#two {
  font-weight: 600;  
}
```

```html
<div>
  <p>This Text in BOLD.</p>
  <p id="one">And we want this in normal weight but we want it to wrap as it is doing in the second example.</p>
</div>
<div>
  <p id="two">This Text in BOLD. And we want this in normal weight but we want it to wrap as it is doing in the second example.</p>
</div>
```

Comment: The layout on the second is still different from the first.  I will edit the example to show the first p in BOLD.

Answer (score 0):

The issue appears to be that a p tag will automagically fill space to the right if not given a width, so we solve the problem by not using p tags, in my case I've chosen to use d tags, but there would be many to choose from.

```css
div {
  width: 200px;
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.6);
  margin: 10px;
  padding: 10px;
}
d {
  margin: 0px;
  color: white;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-weight: 100;
}
d:nth-child(1) {
  font-weight: 600;  
}
```

```html
<div>
  <d>This Text in BOLD.</d>
  <d>And we want this in normal weight but we want it to wrap as it is doing in the second example.</d>
</div>
<div>
  <d>This Text in BOLD. And we want this in normal weight but we want it to wrap as it is doing in the second example.</d>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use `display:inline;` this align your `p tag` into `inline box elements` and thus this align your output as you want.

> display:inline - The element generates one or more inline element
>   boxes.

```
div:nth-child(1) > p:nth-child(1) {
      font-weight: 600;  
      display:inline;
}
div:nth-child(1) > p:nth-child(2) {
       margin:0;
       display:inline;
}
```

```css
div {
  width: 200px;
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.6);
  margin: 10px;
  padding: 10px;
}
p {
  margin: 0px;
  color: white;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-weight: 100;
}
div:nth-child(1) > p:nth-child(1) {
  font-weight: 600;  
  display:inline;
}
div:nth-child(1) > p:nth-child(2) {
   margin:0;
   display:inline;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <p>This Text in BOLD.</p>
  <p>And we want this in normal weight but we want it to wrap as it is doing in the second example.</p>
</div>
<div>
  <p>This Text in BOLD. And we want this in normal weight but we want it to wrap as it is doing in the second example.</p>
</div>
```